# How to detect which assemblies require the Partially Trusted Callers Attribute?

Tags: .net, security, attributes, partial-trust

I have downloaded a web project from CodePlex and am getting the following error in Application_Start:

> System.Security.SecurityException:
>   That assembly does not allow partially
>   trusted callers.

This project references several other assemblies from other open source projects. My theory is that one of these do not have the **AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers** attribute set (all of the assemblies in the CodePlex project do).

How can I tell which assemblies have this attribute set, and which don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've missed something in your question, but these assemblies that your referencing, can you open them in [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm)? Using that will allow you to view the `<Assembly:()>` attributes for the file, which should show whether they have the APTC attribute set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out - I just used Reflector on the assemblies. Every `[assembly]` attribute is listed there including

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```